# Tokenize words in a list of sentences Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, text, nltk

i currently have a file that contains a list that is looks like

```
example = ['Mary had a little lamb' , 
           'Jack went up the hill' , 
           'Jill followed suit' ,    
           'i woke up suddenly' ,
           'it was a really bad dream...']
```

"example" is a list of such sentences , and i want the output to look as :

`mod_example = ["'Mary' 'had' 'a' 'little' 'lamb'" , 'Jack' 'went' 'up' 'the' 'hill' ....]`
and so on. 
I need the sentences to be separate with each word tokenized so that i can compare each word from a sentence of `mod_example` (at a time using for loop) with a reference sentence.

I tried this :

```
for sentence in example:
    text3 = sentence.split()
    print text3
```

and got the follwing as output :

```
['it', 'was', 'a', 'really', 'bad', 'dream...']
```

**How do I get this for all the sentences?** 
it keeps overwriting . and yes , also mention whether my approach is right?
this should remain a list of sentences with the words tokenized.. thanks

Comment: Can you explain more thoroughly what you mean with ".. so that i can compare each word from a sentence of mod_example (at a time using for loop) with a reference sentence."

Comment: the " mean that each sentence is still a separate entity. so i want words to be tokenized , not the entire text. for eg: i dont want ['mary' 'had' 'a' 'little' 'lamb' jack' 'went' 'up' 'the' 'hill'] and so on. it should still be a list with each sentence having tokenized words..

Comment: The question as asked has **nothing to do with** tokenizing input; it is purely about how to apply existing code to a list of inputs, repeating it for each element.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You could use the word tokenizer in NLTK (http://nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html) with a list comprehension, see http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

```
>>> from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
>>> example = ['Mary had a little lamb' , 
...            'Jack went up the hill' , 
...            'Jill followed suit' ,    
...            'i woke up suddenly' ,
...            'it was a really bad dream...']
>>> tokenized_sents = [word_tokenize(i) for i in example]
>>> for i in tokenized_sents:
...     print i
... 
['Mary', 'had', 'a', 'little', 'lamb']
['Jack', 'went', 'up', 'the', 'hill']
['Jill', 'followed', 'suit']
['i', 'woke', 'up', 'suddenly']
['it', 'was', 'a', 'really', 'bad', 'dream', '...']
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend against NLTK. Albeit popular (due to being the first well-documented Python NLP package), it is long out-dated. Moreover, `word_tokenize` has a habit of transforming the input.

Comment: Agreed on transforming the input but IMHO tokenization should not be seen as a transformation but an annotation. Annotation is adding layers of information on top of the data, not replacing the data =) (Disclaimer: I do contribute to NLTK)

Comment: Also, there are more than 1 tokenizer in NLTK, the original treebank tokenizer widely used by the NLP community althought out-dated isn't a one size fit all silver bullet. And since https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1214 , there has been a lot more tokenizers incorporated/ported/wrapped into NLTK, includes Moses (from machine translation), Toktok (from language modeling), REPP (from grammar engineering) and Stanford CoreNLP tokenizers for multiple langauges (https://github.com/nltk/nltk/pull/1735#issuecomment-306091826)

Comment: If anyone is looking for speed and customizable tokenizers, please do look into SpaCy tokenizer https://spacy.io/docs/usage/customizing-tokenizer. It'll be great if there's a similar contribution of that in NLTK too =)

Answer (score 8):

i make this script to make all people understood how to tokenize, so they can build their Natural Language Processing's engine by them self.

```
import re
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
from io import StringIO

example = 'Mary had a little lamb, Jack went up the hill, Jill followed suit, i woke up suddenly, it was a really bad dream...'

def token_to_sentence(str):
    f = StringIO()
    with redirect_stdout(f):
        regex_of_sentence = re.findall('([\w\s]{0,})[^\w\s]', str)
        regex_of_sentence = [x for x in regex_of_sentence if x is not '']
        for i in regex_of_sentence:
            print(i)
        first_step_to_sentence = (f.getvalue()).split('\n')
    g = StringIO()
    with redirect_stdout(g):
        for i in first_step_to_sentence:
            try:
                regex_to_clear_sentence = re.search('\s([\w\s]{0,})', i)
                print(regex_to_clear_sentence.group(1))
            except:
                print(i)
        sentence = (g.getvalue()).split('\n')
    return sentence

def token_to_words(str):
    f = StringIO()
    with redirect_stdout(f):
        for i in str:
            regex_of_word = re.findall('([\w]{0,})', i)
            regex_of_word = [x for x in regex_of_word if x is not '']
            for word in regex_of_word:
                print(regex_of_word)
        words = (f.getvalue()).split('\n')
```

i make a different process, i restart the process from paragraph, to make everybody more understood of word processing. paragraph to process is:

```
example = 'Mary had a little lamb, Jack went up the hill, Jill followed suit, i woke up suddenly, it was a really bad dream...'
```

tokenize paragraph to sentence:

```
sentence = token_to_sentence(example)
```

will result:

```
['Mary had a little lamb', 'Jack went up the hill', 'Jill followed suit', 'i woke up suddenly', 'it was a really bad dream']
```

tokenize to words:

```
words = token_to_words(sentence)
```

will result:

```
['Mary', 'had', 'a', 'little', 'lamb', 'Jack', 'went, 'up', 'the', 'hill', 'Jill', 'followed', 'suit', 'i', 'woke', 'up', 'suddenly', 'it', 'was', 'a', 'really', 'bad', 'dream']
```

i will explain how this work.

first, i used regex to search all word and spaces which separate the words and stop until found a punctuation, the regex is:

```
([\w\s]{0,})[^\w\s]{0,}
```

so the computation wil be took the words and spaces in bracket:

```
'(Mary had a little lamb),( Jack went up the hill, Jill followed suit),( i woke up suddenly),( it was a really bad dream)...'
```

the result is still not clear, contain some 'None' characters. so i used this script to removed the 'None' characters:

```
[x for x in regex_of_sentence if x is not '']
```

so the paragraph will tokenize to sentence, but not clear sentence the result is:

```
['Mary had a little lamb', ' Jack went up the hill', ' Jill followed suit', ' i woke up suddenly', ' it was a really bad dream']
```

as you see the result show some sentence start by a space. so to make a clear paragraph without starting a space, i make this regex:

```
\s([\w\s]{0,})
```

it will make a clear sentence like:

```
['Mary had a little lamb', 'Jack went up the hill', 'Jill followed suit', 'i woke up suddenly', 'it was a really bad dream']
```

so, we must make two process to make a good result.

the answer of your question is start from here...

to tokenize the sentence to words, i make the paragraph iteration and used regex just to capture the word while it was iterating with this regex:

```
([\w]{0,})
```

and clear the empty characters again with:

```
[x for x in regex_of_word if x is not '']
```

so the result is really clear only the list of words:

```
['Mary', 'had', 'a', 'little', 'lamb', 'Jack', 'went, 'up', 'the', 'hill', 'Jill', 'followed', 'suit', 'i', 'woke', 'up', 'suddenly', 'it', 'was', 'a', 'really', 'bad', 'dream']
```

in the future to make a good NLP, you need to have your own phrase database and search if the phrase is in the sentence, after make a list of phrase, the rest of words is clear a word.

with this method, i can build my own NLP in my language (bahasa Indonesia) which really-really lack of module.

edited:

i don't see your question that want to compare the words. so you have another sentence to compare....i give you bonus not only bonus, i give you how to count it.

```
mod_example = ["'Mary' 'had' 'a' 'little' 'lamb'" , 'Jack' 'went' 'up' 'the' 'hill']
```

in this case the step you must do is:
1. iter the mod_example
2. compare the first sentence with the words from mod_example.
3. make some calculation

so the script will be:

```
import re
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
from io import StringIO

example = 'Mary had a little lamb, Jack went up the hill, Jill followed suit, i woke up suddenly, it was a really bad dream...'
mod_example = ["'Mary' 'had' 'a' 'little' 'lamb'" , 'Jack' 'went' 'up' 'the' 'hill']

def token_to_sentence(str):
    f = StringIO()
    with redirect_stdout(f):
        regex_of_sentence = re.findall('([\w\s]{0,})[^\w\s]', str)
        regex_of_sentence = [x for x in regex_of_sentence if x is not '']
        for i in regex_of_sentence:
            print(i)
        first_step_to_sentence = (f.getvalue()).split('\n')
    g = StringIO()
    with redirect_stdout(g):
        for i in first_step_to_sentence:
            try:
                regex_to_clear_sentence = re.search('\s([\w\s]{0,})', i)
                print(regex_to_clear_sentence.group(1))
            except:
                print(i)
        sentence = (g.getvalue()).split('\n')
    return sentence

def token_to_words(str):
    f = StringIO()
    with redirect_stdout(f):
        for i in str:
            regex_of_word = re.findall('([\w]{0,})', i)
            regex_of_word = [x for x in regex_of_word if x is not '']
            for word in regex_of_word:
                print(regex_of_word)
        words = (f.getvalue()).split('\n')

def convert_to_words(str):
    sentences = token_to_sentence(str)
    for i in sentences:
        word = token_to_words(i)
    return word

def compare_list_of_words__to_another_list_of_words(from_strA, to_strB):
        fromA = list(set(from_strA))
        for word_to_match in fromA:
            totalB = len(to_strB)
            number_of_match = (to_strB).count(word_to_match)
            data = str((((to_strB).count(word_to_match))/totalB)*100)
            print('words: -- ' + word_to_match + ' --' + '\n'
            '       number of match    : ' + number_of_match + ' from ' + str(totalB) + '\n'
            '       percent of match   : ' + data + ' percent')



#prepare already make, now we will use it. The process start with script below:

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #tokenize paragraph in example to sentence:
    getsentences = token_to_sentence(example)

    #tokenize sentence to words (sentences in getsentences)
    getwords = token_to_words(getsentences)

    #compare list of word in (getwords) with list of words in mod_example
    compare_list_of_words__to_another_list_of_words(getwords, mod_example)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use nltk (as [@alvas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21361623/3406616) suggests) and a recursive function which takes any object and tokenize each str in it:

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
def tokenize(obj):
    if obj is None:
        return None
    elif isinstance(obj, str):
        return word_tokenize(obj)
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        return [tokenize(i) for i in obj]
    else:
        return obj # Or throw an exception, or parse a dict...
```

Usage:

```
data = [["Lorem ipsum dolor. Sit amet?", "Hello World!", None], ["a"], "Hi!", None, ""]
print(tokenize(data))
```

Output:

```
[[['Lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', '.', 'Sit', 'amet', '?'], ['Hello', 'World', '!'], None], [['a']], ['Hi', '!'], None, []]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Break down the list "Example"

```
first_split = []

for i in example:

    first_split.append(i.split())
```

## Break down the elements of first_split list

```
second_split = []

for j in first_split:

    for k in j:

        second_split.append(k.split())
```

## Break down the elements of the second_split list and append it to the final list, how the coder need the output

```
final_list = []

for m in second_split:

    for n in m:

        if(n not in final_list):

            final_list.append(n)

print(final_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

This also can be done by `pytorch` torchtext as

```
from torchtext.data import get_tokenizer

tokenizer = get_tokenizer('basic_english')
example = ['Mary had a little lamb' , 
            'Jack went up the hill' , 
            'Jill followed suit' ,    
            'i woke up suddenly' ,
            'it was a really bad dream...']
tokens = []
for s in example:
    tokens += tokenizer(s)
# ['mary', 'had', 'a', 'little', 'lamb', 'jack', 'went', 'up', 'the', 'hill', 'jill', 'followed', 'suit', 'i', 'woke', 'up', 'suddenly', 'it', 'was', 'a', 'really', 'bad', 'dream', '.', '.', '.']
```

Answer (score 1):

use a list comprehension to access your sentence then word_tokenize it.

```
 from nltk import word_tokenize
 sentences = ['Mary had a little lamb' , 
        'Jack went up the hill' , 
        'Jill followed suit' ,    
        'i woke up suddenly' ,
        'it was a really bad dream...']

 sentences = [ word_tokenize ( sent ) for sent in sentences ]

 print(sentences)
```

output:

```
 [['Mary', 'had', 'a', 'little', 'lamb'], ['Jack', 'went', 'up', 'the', 'hill'], ['Jill', 'followed', 'suit'], ['i', 'woke', 'up', 'suddenly'], ['it', 'was', 'a', 'really', 'bad', 'dream', '...']]
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it's hard to tell, what you are trying to do.

How about this

```
exclude = set(['Mary', 'Jack', 'Jill', 'i', 'it'])

mod_example = []
for sentence in example:
    words = sentence.split()
    # Optionally sort out some words
    for word in words:
        if word in exclude:
            words.remove(word)
    mod_example.append('\'' + '\' \''.join(words) + '\'')

print mod_example
```

Which ouputs

```
["'had' 'a' 'little' 'lamb'", "'went' 'up' 'the' 'hill'", "'followed' 'suit'", 
"'woke' 'up' 'suddenly'", "'was' 'a' 'really' 'bad' 'dream...'"]
>>>
```

Edit:
Another suggestion based on further info given by the OP

```
example = ['Area1 Area1 street one, 4454 hikoland' ,
           'Area2 street 2, 52432 hikoland, area2' ,
           'Area3 ave three, 0534 hikoland' ]

mod_example = []
for sentence in example:
    words = sentence.split()
    # Sort out some words
    col1 = words[0]
    col2 = words[1:]
    if col1 in col2:
        col2.remove(col1)
    elif col1.lower() in col2:
        col2.remove(col1.lower())
    mod_example.append(col1 + ': ' + ' '.join(col2))
```

Outputs

```
>>>> print mod_example
['Area1: street one, 4454 hikoland', 'Area2: street 2, 52432 hikoland,', 
'Area3: ave three, 0534 hikoland']
>>>
```

Comment: is this still a list? this is what i want.. and yes, i want the first word of each sentence too.. thanks.. i'll check this out

Comment: It would be much easier, @Sword, if you'd tell, what is the basic problem, that you are solving.

Comment: @Sword It's just that if you ask about precise operations, no one will be able to show an alternative way of solving the underlying problem

Comment: ohhk. i'll elaborate . suppose i have a tsv file which shows the area name in 1 column , and the exact address(like building name,street etc) in 2nd column. there are many such addresses in the form as [jack went up the hill , jill followed suit] where the comma represents the next line. the 1st column uses autofill , so the area name is right, but the 2nd column may have mistakes . the area name might be entered by mistake in this 2nd column(exact address). what i need to do is compare the 1st with 2nd and remove the area name duplicate if it appears in column 2..

Comment: If commas separate lines, what are columns separated with, @Sword?

Comment: it is a tsv , that is tab separated file. and i have used commas to represent different rows for u to understand(actually there are many commas in a single row and it doesnt detemine anything in this case) ..   
eg:
green hill zone |  small hut , 4th avenue road, next to corn farm.

evergreen woods |  big hut, off 8th mile road , evergreen woods.

as u can see , i need to remove the duplicate from the 2nd column ,i.e evergreen woods , coz its already in 1st column.. 
any idea??

Answer (score 0):

In Spacy it will be as simple as :

```
import spacy

example = ['Mary had a little lamb' , 
           'Jack went up the hill' , 
           'Jill followed suit' ,    
           'i woke up suddenly' ,
           'it was a really bad dream...']

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

result = []

for line in example:
    sent = nlp(line)
    token_result = []
    for token in sent:
        token_result.append(token)
    result.append(token_result)

print(result)
```

And the output will be :

```
[[Mary, had, a, little, lamb], [Jack, went, up, the, hill], [Jill, followed, suit], [i, woke, up, suddenly], [it, was, a, really, bad, dream, ...]]
```